# Twilio error sending bulk messages w/ PFcloud

Tags: javascript, parsing, twilio

I am getting [Error]: Uh oh, something went wrong (Code: 141, Version: 1.12.0)" everytime I try to send an SMS to more than 100 numbers at once. below is my code. any ideas?

```
var endpoint = "https://api.twilio.com/" + config.get("twilioAPIVersion") + "/Accounts/" + config.get("twilioSID") + "/Messages.json";
    var authorization = config.get("twilioSID") + ":" + config.get("twilioAuthToken");
    authorization = "Basic " + Buffer.from(authorization).toString("base64"); // Basic auth, base64 encoding tokens

    // Send the messages
    var sendPromises = [];
    params.to.forEach(function(phoneNumber) {
        var formattedNumber = phoneFormatter(phoneNumber)[0];
        formattedRecipients.push(formattedNumber);
        sendPromises.push(Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
            method: "POST",
            url: endpoint,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "Authorization": authorization
            },
            body: {
                "To": formattedNumber,
                "From": twilioNumber.get("number"),
                "Body": params.message
            }
        }));
    });

    return Parse.Promise.when(sendPromises);
```

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio has a limit of [100 concurrent API requests](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002943027-Understanding-Twilio-Rate-Limits-and-Message-Queues) at a time, after that it will start returning errors to you. I would split up your messages to be sent in groups of 100 or less and add delays between them to overcome this. Alternatively, you could look into using [Twilio Notify to send bulk SMS messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/notify/guides/sms-quickstart). Notify allows you to make one call to the API to send messages and will take care of queueing them and sending them itself.